# VBA Code for an Update button on a form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a form that has an unbound combobox (cboJack) and 7 Unbound Text Fields (txtID, txtSwitch, txtPortNumber, txtVoiceVLAN, txtdataVLAN, txtCableNumber, txtcomments3)

Whenever I choose an option from the combobox, the 7 text fields are autopopulated through the use of the following code:

```
Private Sub cboJack_Change()
Me.txtID = Me.cboJack.Column(0)
Me.txtSwitch = Me.cboJack.Column(2)
Me.txtPortNumber = Me.cboJack.Column(3)
Me.txtVoiceVLAN = Me.cboJack.Column(4)
Me.txtdataVLAN = Me.cboJack.Column(5)
Me.txtCableNumber = Me.cboJack.Column(6)
Me.txtComments3 = Me.cboJack.Column(7)
End Sub
```

I have created an update button on the form so that after I select value from the combobox and everything autopopulates, I can edit whatever fields I want, and then press the update button to save everything. Some of the fields are number fields and some are text fields. For some reason I'm getting a syntax error. Here is the code I have for my command button.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "UPDATE Switches SET Switch = '" & Me.txtSwitch & "', [Port Number] = " & Me.txtPortNumber & ", [Voice VLAN] = " & Me.txtVoiceVLAN & ", [Data VLAN] = " & Me.txtdataVLAN & ", [Cable Number] = " & Me.txtCableNumber & ", [Comments] = '" & Me.txtComments3 & "' WHERE Jack = '" & Me.cboJack & "'"

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
End Sub
```

The number type columns are, Port Number, Voice VLAN, DataVLAN and Cable Number. ID is autonumber, and the rest are text columns.

I think the reason why there's a problem is that some of the fields in Port Number, Voice VLAN, data VLAN and Cable Number don't have any values (Some of the values are null)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `strSQL` after you create it but before you run the command?

Comment: isn't it nothing until I run the command? Sorry I may not be understanding your question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is most likely that the problem is caused by Null values in your non-string elements.

Here is a quick and easy fix:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Switches SET Switch = '" & Me.txtSwitch & "', " & _
" [Port Number] = " & Nz(Me.txtPortNumber,"NULL") & ", " & _
" [Voice VLAN] = " & Nz(Me.txtVoiceVLAN,"NULL") & ", " & _
" [Data VLAN] = " & Nz(Me.txtdataVLAN,"NULL") & ", " & _
" [Cable Number] = " & Nz(Me.txtCableNumber,"NULL") & ", " & _
" [Comments] = '" & Me.txtComments3 & "' WHERE Jack = '" & Me.cboJack & "'"
```

So you actually replace the null values (causing the sql statement to have syntax errors such as : `[column] = , [column2] = ,` ) with the string `NULL`

Sample result : `[column] = NULL, [column2] = NULL,`

**Edit : Using IIf to check for an empty string**

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Switches SET Switch = '" & Me.txtSwitch & "', " & _
" [Port Number] = " & IIf(Len(Nz(Me.txtPortNumber)) = 0 , "NULL",Me.txtPortNumber) & ", " & _
" [Voice VLAN] = " & IIf(Len(Nz(Me.txtVoiceVLAN)) = 0 , "NULL", Me.txtVoiceVLAN) & ", " & _
" [Data VLAN] = " & IIf(Len(Nz(Me.txtdataVLAN)) = 0 , "NULL", Me.txtdataVLAN)& ", " & _
" [Cable Number] = " & IIf(Len(Nz(Me.txtCableNumber)) = 0 , "NULL", Me.txtCableNumber) & ", " & _
" [Comments] = '" & Me.txtComments3 & "' WHERE Jack = '" & Me.cboJack & "'"
```

Comment: hmm, I'm still getting a syntax error with the Update Statement

Comment: try the following : Replace the `Nz` function with an `Iif` as follows : `IIf(Len(Nz(Me.txtSth)) = 0 , "NULL", Me.txtSth)`

Comment: Also try adding a `Msgbox strSQL` before the actual `DoCmd.RunSQL` to see the string's value

Comment: the error is gone, but now whenever I edit a field and i press update, it says "do you want to update 0 rows" when I changed 1 or more rows.

Comment: verify that the bound column of your combo box is indeed the one you want to include in your query (I am guessing it is the ID). Also try using the msgbox and add what the query string is so we can see it.

Comment: The bound column is not the ID but it's the Jack Column. I'm using the ID just as a reference as I need that ID for another table. Sorry, I'm quite new to access and thank you for being so patient.

Comment: No problem :) Change your where statement to `Me.cboJack.Column(whateverNumberTheJackColumnIs)`. And please do add the query string, it will be very helpful :)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! just one more thing, what do you mean by add the query string? Slash how do I do it. (Seems like a simple answer but I'm actually not quite sure how to do it) :(

Comment: Just printing the string to your screen. You can use the `Msgbox` as mentioned in my comment above, `Debug.Print` to show it in the console window or simply add it to the watch list and add a breakpoint to debug in the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using a SQL Update at all in your case. Other than the Null issue, your Update will also fail if someone enters a non-numeric character in one of the numeric fields, or an apostrophe in the Comments. (or worse: think "SQL injection")

When working with textboxes and text fields, Access cheerfully replaces empty strings with Null. You can either fight against it, or just "go with the flow" and use a method that handles empty strings and apostrophes safely and with no extra work.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Switches")
    .FindFirst ("Jack = '" & cboJack & "'")
    If .NoMatch Then
        '' add a new record perhaps?
    Else
        .Edit
        .Fields("Switch") = txtSwitch
        .Fields("Port Number") = txtPortNumber
        .Fields("Voice VLAN") = txtVoiceVLAN
        .Fields("Data VLAN") = txtdataVLAN
        .Fields("Cable Number") = txtCableNumber
        .Fields("Comments") = txtComments3
        .Update
    End If
End With
End Sub
```